# Is conditional import pythonic

Tags: python

```
storage_type = parser.get(Section, "storage")
if "DB" == storage_type:
    from proxy.db_storage import Storage
elif "FS" == storage_type:
    from proxy.fs_storage import Storage
...work with Storage..
```

I need to use just one of two modules to load the class depending on config variable, so is the above approach fine?

Comment: You need to handle the remaining case (neither DB nor FS).

Comment: I omit the remaining case intentionally